# Javascript метод append

Tags: javascript

написал тестовую функцию

```
function Test1(){
    let addDIV=document.createElement('div');
    addDIV.innerHTML="<b>Text</b>";
    let div1=document.getElementById("div_container");
    let div2=document.getElementById("TestDiv")

    div1.append(addDIV);
    addDIV.innerHTML="<b>Text New</b>";
    div2.append(addDIV);
}
```

По моей логике при вызове addDiv должен был добавиться сначала в div1, с текстом Text, а потом добавится к div2 с текстом Text New. На практике происходит добавление сначала к div1, потом из div1 содержимое удаляется и добавляется в div2. Почему так работает? Это особенность работы append которая не позволяет добавлять один и тот же объект для разных родителей, или дело в чем-то другом?

Пробовал в Chrome 80 и FF 72

Отображение в браузере ниже.

[image: Вывод в браузере]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну тут элементарно всё. Вы создали некий DOM node. Это объект. У него есть свойство parentNode - то, где он расположен в дереве. Сделав в первый раз append вы сказали ему где лежать, то есть изменили свойство addDIV.parentNode. Сделав второй раз append вы просто поменяли значение свойства parentNode у addDIV, потому он просто переместился.

Посему, вам нужно клонировать, например, так:

```
div1.append(addDIV);
var copyAddDIV = Object.assign(document.createElement('div'), addDIV);
copyAddDIV.innerHTML="<b>Text New</b>";
div2.append(copyAddDIV);
```